# Создание dll библиотеки для windows на языке c++

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

Доброго времени суток.

Пытаюсь вынести пару функций в dll библиотеку.
Пробовал уже несколько вариантов:

- пример с http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL.
- пример из Рихтер "Создание эффективных Win-23 приложений"
- и множество других примеров с просторов сети.

В приложенном коде используется вариант, используемый моим одногруппником, у него все работает корректно.
Я использую компилятор MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1.

Мог бы кто-то объяснить на пальцах или дать ссылку на реальный пример создания и явного связывания dll, как экспортировать функции и структуры. Спасибо

```
// testdll.h
#include <windows.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

extern "C++"{
    struct line{
        POINT start;
        POINT end;
    };    

    __declspec(dllexport) void reDraw(HWND hWnd, HDC hdc, HPEN pen, bool df, POINT cp, vector< struct line > &lines);
    __declspec(dllexport) WNDCLASS InitializeWndClass(HINSTANCE hInstance, WNDPROC WProc, LPCTSTR ClassName,
                                                      LPCTSTR MenuName, UINT style, HICON Icon, HCURSOR cursor, 
                                                      HBRUSH Bground, int ClsExtra, int WndExtra);
}

// testdll.cpp
#include "testdll.h"

extern "C++"
{
    extern "C++" __declspec(dllexport) void reDraw(HWND hWnd, HDC hdc, HPEN pen, bool df, POINT cp, vector< struct line > &lines)
    {
        hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        SelectObject(hdc, pen);

        if (df){
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, true);
            UpdateWindow(hWnd);

            lines.back().end = cp;

            for (const auto curLine : lines){
                POINT tmp[2] = {curLine.start, curLine.end};
                Polyline(hdc, tmp, 2);
            }
        }
    }

    extern "C++" __declspec(dllexport) WNDCLASS InitializeWndClass(HINSTANCE hInstance, WNDPROC WProc,
                                                                   LPCTSTR ClassName, LPCTSTR MenuName,
                                                                   UINT style, HICON Icon, HCURSOR cursor,
                                                                   HBRUSH Bground, int ClsExtra, int WndExtra)
    {
        WNDCLASS *wc = new WNDCLASS;
        wc->hInstance = hInstance;
        wc->lpszClassName = ClassName;
        wc->lpfnWndProc = WProc;
        wc->style = style;
        wc->hIcon = Icon;
        wc->hCursor = cursor;
        wc->lpszMenuName = MenuName;
        wc->cbClsExtra = ClsExtra;
        wc->cbWndExtra = WndExtra;
        wc->hbrBackground = Bground;

        return *wc;
    }
}

// test.cpp
#include <windows.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string> 
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

HINSTANCE hDLL;
typedef void(*reDraw_func_type)(HWND hWnd, HDC hdc, HPEN pen, bool df, POINT cp, vector< struct line > &lines);
typedef WNDCLASS(*classInit_func_type)(HINSTANCE hInstance, WNDPROC WProc, LPCTSTR ClassName, LPCTSTR MenuName,
                                       UINT style, HICON Icon, HCURSOR cursor, HBRUSH Bground, int ClsExtra, int WndExtra);

reDraw_func_type updateWnd;
classInit_func_type clsInit;

HDC hdc;
HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 4, RGB(255, 0, 0));

POINT currentPoint;

vector< struct line > scene;
bool DrawFlag = false;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE This,  HINSTANCE Prev, LPSTR cmd, int mode) 
{
    hDLL = LoadLibrary("testdll.dll");
    if (!hDLL){
        printf("fail to load dll");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        printf("Dll loaded\n");
        updateWnd = (reDraw_func_type)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "reDraw");
        if (!updateWnd){
            printf("Error to load reDraw func\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("reDraw func had been loaded");
        }
        clsInit = (classInit_func_type)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "InitializeWndClass");
        if (!clsInit){
            printf("Error to load clsInit func\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("clsInit func had been loaded");
        }
        if (!updateWnd || !clsInit){
            FreeLibrary(hDLL);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    WNDCLASS wc = clsInit(This, WndProc, "MainFrame", NULL, (CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW), LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION),
                          LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW), (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1), 0, 0);

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "register class error", "Error", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow("MainFrame", "template", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 500, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, This, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, mode);

    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    FreeLibrary(hDLL);
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:{
            struct line newLine = {
                    currentPoint, // start point
                    currentPoint // end point
            };
            if (!DrawFlag) DrawFlag = true;
            scene.push_back(newLine);
            break;
        }
        case WM_RBUTTONDOWN: {
            DrawFlag = false;
            break;
        }
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE: {
            GetCursorPos(&currentPoint);
            ScreenToClient(hWnd, &currentPoint);

            updateWnd(hWnd, hdc, pen, DrawFlag, currentPoint, scene);
            break;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так это рабочий код или нет?

Comment: По хорошему объявлять надо `<тип> __declspec(dllexport) <имя функции>` и все extern "c++" в .cpp лишние. И у вас нет самого главного, функции входа в длл.

Comment: Пример с mingw.org на первый взгляд рабочий. Что именно в нем непонятно? "*как экспортировать функции и структуры*" - структуру никак не надо экспортировать, она передается через заголовочный файл. В DLL, на уровне бинарников, структур нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас нет главного, точки входа в длл:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dllmain

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
      DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
  switch (fdwReason)
  {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:  // Подключение DLL
      // Выполняем все необходимые
      // действия по инициализации

      // если инициализация прошла
      // успешно возвращаем TRUE
      // в противном случае – FALSE
      return 1; 

    case: DLL_PROCESS_DETACH: // Отключение DLL
      // Выполняем все действия
      // по деинициализации
      break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH: // Создание нового потока
      // Переходим на многопоточную версию,
      // если необходимо
      break;

    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH: // Завершение потока
      // Освобождаем переменные, связанные с потоком
      break;
  }
    return TRUE;  // Возвращаем что-нибудь (все равно
        // код возврата игнорируется)
}
```

и например динамическая загрузка вашей длл в приложении:

```
main()
{
  // Загружаем библиотеку
  HINSTANCE h = LoadLibrary("Test.dll");
  if (!h){ printf("Ошибка загрузки DLL"); return;}

  FreeLibrary(h);      // Выгружаем библиотеку
}
```

или статистическая линковка путем указания флага в командной строке gcc `-lTest`

Правильный подход - определить и использовать собственные флаги для сборки библиотеки и приложения.

Когда собираете приложение, с помощью определенных ранее флагов, функции должны определяться как `dllimport`, когда библиотеку `dllexport`, тогда  заголовок можно использовать в обеих случаях, для сборки библиотеки и приложения,например:

```
    #if defined(BUILD_DLL)
    #define DLLOPT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
    #define DLLOPT extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
```

и соответственно в файле заголовков определять функции и классы через этот макрос:

```
    void DLLOPT myfunction(...);
```

Командная строка для сборки библиотеки для gcc соответственно будет:

```
    gcc ... -DBUILD_DLL=1 ...
```

Для сборки приложения этот флаг не указывается.

Хеадер вашей библиотеки должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
#if defined(BUILD_DLL)
#  define DLLOPT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLLOPT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

struct line
{
    POINT start;
    POINT end;
};    

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

     void DLLOPT reDraw(
          HWND hWnd, HDC hdc, HPEN pen, bool df,
          POINT cp, vector<struct line> &lines);
     WNDCLASS DLLOPT InitializeWndClass(
          HINSTANCE hInstance, WNDPROC WProc, LPCTSTR ClassName,
          LPCTSTR MenuName, UINT style, HICON Icon, HCURSOR cursor,
          HBRUSH Bground, int ClsExtra, int WndExtra);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

И удалить из вашего `.cpp` файла библиотеки все упоминания `extern "C++"`.

Пример который вы привели неполный, и мягко говоря странный для структуры `.dll` http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL

Это больше напоминает заготовку для сборки в формате `.a/.so` и нацелен на операционные системы *nix.

Comment: Точка входа в dll не нужна.

Comment: @VTT, как так? ненужна?

Comment: Вот так. Не нужна. В некоторых особых ситуациях действительно может понадобиться произвести некоторые действия при аттаче / деттаче, однако это явно не тот случай. Так что обычно в ней нет совершенно никакой необходимости.

Comment: `Система также вызывает функцию точки входа для DLL, когда она загружается или выгружается с использованием функций LoadLibrary и FreeLibrary .` - без точки входа это не работает, как минимум.

Comment: Короче попробуйте собрать бибилиотеку без DllMain - все будет работать. Для инициализации рантайма точку входа может сгенерировать компилятор.

Comment: @VTT, возможно, если линковаться статически, у меня не приходило мысли так пробывать, без точки входа :)

Comment: @VTT, `точку входа может сгенерировать компилятор` - мне кажется это ключевое слово, надо проверить. Вангую, `VC++` наверняка это делает, а вот `mingw+gcc` вероятно нет, тогда проблема ТС очевидна. Кроме проблем с лишними `extern C++` в коде

Comment: Вот VC++ может спокойно этого не делать, а gcc наверное обязательно вставляет всякие _init и _fini

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, хотелось бы уточнить: в хедере указаны 'dllimport', но я же хочу экспортировать функции из библиотеки, второе: как экспортируются структуры( тк при попытке компиляции файла основной программы, с исправленным хедером, я получаю несколько ошибок __variable 'line newLine' has initializer but incomplete type__ __forward declaration of 'struct line'__, и последнее: может быть я что-то не понимаю, но я собираю dll так - g++ - c testdll.cpp g++ -shared -o testdll.dll testdll.o -lgdi32 - может я и здесь где-то не прав.

Comment: @NewView Спасибо за помощь, единственное, я так и не смог экспортировать структуру и к сожалению не смог найти какую-либо понятную информацию на этот счет, поэтому (если вас не затруднит) могли бы вы объяснить как это происходит, и как это нужно описать. Спасибо.

Comment: По хорошему надо использовать флаги компилятора для сборки библиотеки и приложения, когда собираете приложение должно быть `dllimport`, когда библиотеку `dllexport`, тогда этот заголовок можно использовать и там, и там.

Comment: Поправил ответ, посмотрите пример, имя структуры поменяйте, например `sline_s`, вероятнее всего с чем то пересекается, и она должна быть одинаково определена и в библиотеке и в программе.