# Компиляция dll библиотеки и ее использование из под линукс

Tags: c++, linux, c, windows

Для компиляции я использовал mingw-w64. Компилятор gcc от mingw. Этот пакет входит в состав ubuntu.
Вопрос интересует и для c++, потому что возможно буду и на нем писать проги. Покапавшись в сети я нашел как скомпилировать dll библиотеку, но там надо было указывать флаги, а я их не указывал. Вот вообще makefile мой в линуксе.

```
GCC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32
all:
        $(GCC) -shared lib.c -o lib.dll
        $(GCC) main.c -o dll.exe
```

Вот исходник самой библиотеки, я читал что надо EXPORT писать в исходнике, но у меня без EXPORT все работает. Вот такой код.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print ( )
{
        printf ( "test\n" );
}
```

Дальше я написал программу тоже по примерам.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
        HANDLE ldll;

        void (*print)( );

        ldll = LoadLibrary ( "lib.dll" );

        print = GetProcAddress ( ldll, "print" );

        print ( );
}
```

Я скомпилировал, запустил программу **dll.exe** через wine. И в итоге вывелось сообщение `test`. Вот вопрос, сильно ли нужны тогда EXPORT и всё такое, если и без них всё работает. И заработает ли это в настоящей windows, не в wine?

Comment: Используй cmake так ты сможешь гарантировать при сборке с помощью gcc запуск под виндовс и линукс. Нечего не изменяя в cmake файле.

Comment: @jNX А как мне так настроить? Я недавно смотрел документацию по cmake, не особо понел как что настраивать, смотрел toolchain документацию.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/155467/ Почитайте следующую статью. В принципе вам будет ее достаточно. Вам необходимо разобраться как подключаются исходные файлы и библиотеки. Дальше просто 1)cmake 2)make и готово )

Comment: @jNX спасибо.!!

Comment: Если не сможешь разобраться напиши мб чем помогу. Если хватает репы можешь чат создать.

Comment: Посмотрите тут, тема создания длл с мингв обсуждалась недавно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/964306/Создание-dll-библиотеки-для-windows-на-языке-c/964312#964312

Comment: @jNX хорошо.!.!